# How to get the string alone in a query instead a tuple?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

When a query is made with `User.object.values_list('username')` is returns `Quersy_set: (('user1',)('user2,)...)` which is a tuple. When i print, it shows `('user1',)`. How to get the `user1`alone, so that i can display it in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is return a flat list and then get the values from the list or iterate through it. To do so, you'd need:

```py
usernames = User.object.values_list('username', flat=True)
```

Then on your template you can do:

```html
{% for username in usernames %}
    Username: {{ username }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks! I found the solution myself for querying the username by just removing the `values_list()` in the end since the `User` model always has the username as the name for it. Anyways, this worked and is the correct way to approach for other fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this It will return the username alone as strings.

for pro in User.objects.all():
       print(pro.username)